# Table formatting: remove horizontal and vertical borders from only specific cells

Tags: tables, formatting

The MWE below creates a 3 x 3 table. The included text above the table describes the specific cells where I want no borders.

I believe the solutions lies with the correctly using `\cline` command combined with `\multicolumn{1}{c|}`.

But I can't figure out the correct syntax to achieve the desired result.

Your assistance is much appreciated!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\title{FACTORbox}
\author{Algebra Teacher Who Struggles with LaTeX Tables}
\date{January 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
In the table below, I only want \textbf{borderlines around the values in black,
} not the red values above and to the left of the black colored values.

Also, I can't figure out a way to \textbf{remove the gray shading from upper left corner cell.}


\def\arraystretch{2}
\begin{tabular}{ |c | c | c | }
 %  \hline
   \cellcolor{gray}& \textcolor{red}{$x$} & \textcolor{red}{$+6$} \\
   \hline
  \textcolor{red}{$x$} & $x^2$ & $6x$ \\
  \hline 
  \textcolor{red}{$+2$} & $2x$ & $12$ \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @zarko ...can't thank you enough for providing this fix -- a solution which eluded me for far too many hours!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this?

[image: screenshot of table]

You have many possibilities, one of them is use `\multicolumn` command which hasn't border lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % <--- 

\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\title{FACTORbox}
\author{Algebra Teacher Who Struggles with LaTeX Tables}
\date{January 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
In the table below, I only want \textbf{borderlines around the values in black,
} not the red values above and to the left of the black colored values.

Also, I can't figure out a way to \textbf{remove the gray shading from upper left corner cell.}


\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{tabular}{ c | c | c | }
 %  \hline
 \mcc{} & \mcc{\textcolor{red}{$x$}} & \mcc{\textcolor{red}{$+6$}} \\
    \cline{2-3}
 \textcolor{red}{$x$} & $x^2$ & $6x$ \\
    \cline{2-3}
 \textcolor{red}{$+2$} & $2x$ & $12$ \\
    \cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

Another possibilities is to use ˙`blkarray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}
$\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{blockarray}{r cc}
    & \textcolor{red}{x} & \textcolor{red}{+6}   \\
    \cline{2-3}
    \begin{block}{r|c|c|}
    \cline{2-3}
\textcolor{red}{x} & x^2 & 6x \\
    \cline{2-3}
\textcolor{red}{+2} & 2x & 12 \\
    \cline{2-3}
    \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
$
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before.

Comment: +1 from me. The image wasn't displaying, so I fixed it. Hope that's ok, revert back if not :)

Comment: @cmhughes, thank you very much for inserting image. I don't know, why it doesn't show up.

Comment: @cmhughes ...much appreciate you fixing the image so it displays!

Answer (score 6):

With the package `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.8}
$\begin{NiceMatrix}%
  [
    hvlines,
    columns-width=auto,
    first-row, code-for-first-row = \color{red},
    first-col, code-for-first-col = \color{red}
  ]
   & x   & +6 \\
x  & x^2 & 6x \\
+2 & 2x  & 12
\end{NiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]